# Android Google Maps Api V2, GPS locationlistener and geocode

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationlistener, google-maps-android-api-2

***NOTE: this question has nothing to do with MapView, MapViewActivity or GeoPoints, that api has been deprecated***

Hello,

I'm having trouble with the android google maps api v2. Specifically I want make sure that the map pans when my location moves, and I want to listen to these events so I can get the string address of that location, as well as the longitude and latitude.

I am sure to get this once right now, but I want to listen to the changes.

My problem is that I am just not sure how much the new map does and what the `LocationSource` object will do for me. The sample application does not use GPS at all.

I'm not sure if I need to implement LocationListener to access the GPS hardware.

I need to be able to pan the map and get the geocoded address on the fly (by running the geocode method after its been detected that the map moved)

Does anyone have working geocoding using android google maps v2? I'm currently:

a) not sure if LocationSource is actually listening to movement changes

b) how to get the movement changes into my map object to update the screen, coordinates, and run geocoding

Comment: Just a heads-up: Google added `OnMyLocationChangeListener`, which is called when a change in location is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) not sure if LocationSource is actually listening to movement changes

*You* are the source of locations if you are using `setLocationSource()`. You will be passed an `OnLocationChangedListener` in your `activate()` method (part of the `LocationSource` interface). You need to call `onLocationChanged()` on that `OnLocationChangedListener` when you get a new location fix, by whatever means you choose (e.g., GPS).

> b) how to get the movement changes into my map object to update the screen, coordinates, and run geocoding

By calling `onLocationChanged()` on that `OnLocationChangedListener`, the `GoogleMap` will be informed about the new location and, if that location is presently visible on the map, will mark it, assuming that you called `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` on the `GoogleMap`. Or, you can update the position of a `Marker` to reflect the user's position yourself.

Geocoding is completely independent of `GoogleMap`. When you get location fixes from whatever means that you choose, you can also run through your geocoding logic in addition to updating the map.

Comment: yes, but I would like you to elaborate on geocoding. Did the api v2 update with a better geocoding object or do I still need to send a rest call to google maps api v3 online

Comment: @CQM: Geocoding is independent of either the Maps V1 (SDK add-on) or Maps V2 (Play Services) Android APIs. [`Geocoder` is part of Android itself](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), and therefore will only change with changes in Android OS versions. The `Geocoder` API  has not changed since API Level 9, and I have no idea if its implementation has changed, let alone improved Sorry!

Comment: I get a location marker when I just use `myMap.setMyLocation(true)` but when I combine that with `myMap.setLocationSource(mLocationSourceObject)` then I don't get a location marker. Left scratching me head on this so far

Comment: @CQM: Well, here's my work-in-progress sample of using `setLocationSource()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location

Comment: Thank you, I'm experimenting with it right now, judging from this map demo.. are you routinely in Manhattan?

Comment: @CQM: I wouldn't describe it as "routinely", but usually I am in NYC a half-dozen or so times per year.

Comment: okay, I added this to your code, `@Override
  public void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
   
   locMgr.removeUpdates(this);
   
  }` it is working very close to ideal right now

Comment: @CQM: Yeah, I should probably add some more sophistication for config changes -- haven't gotten there yet with the Maps V2 samples.

Comment: can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980823/android-google-maps-api-v2-getting-the-coordinates-for-the-current-map-center