# Android Google Maps Api V2, getting the coordinates for the current map center

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Android Google Maps Api V2 (not MapView or MapActivity) and I am having difficulty getting the coordinates for the center of the map.

I was thinking of using

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    geoCodeCenter(/*Location object*/);
}
```

but I can't get the lat/long from the CameraPosition object. the camera also has more dimensions as you can look at the map at different pitches now too, so getting the center of for latitude/longitude isn't the same since the user isn't guaranteed to be looking at the map from birds eye view, unless certain gestures are disabled.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want the user to have to long click a marker to drag it around the map, I want them to just know where the center of the map is by the user panning it around.

the `map.getMyLocation()` method is for something else, like the current LocationProvider position. Also not seemingly the option, notwithstanding the fact that I am using GPS and it still returns null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but I can't get the lat/long from the CameraPosition object

The [`target` public data member](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition#target) on a `CameraPosition` is a `LatLng` of the map center, based upon my reading of the docs.

Comment: LatLng latLng=googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
It worked thanks.

Comment: it's not necessarily at the center of the visible region because of the mercator projection, do you know how to calculate the actual mid point of the visible region?